# How do I read a matrix from workspace in simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to read a matrix variable from the workspace in Simulink. I am using the `simin` block but I have a problem with this.  It shows me the following error:

> Invalid workspace variable specified as workspace input in
>   'untitled1/From Workspace'. Time values must be monotonically
>   increasing.

Which properties of this block (`simin`) or the matrix variable in workspace should I change to read it in simulink with the block correctly and operate with it (Multiply, Transpose....)?

Comment: If you want the entire matrix in one time step the easiest way is to use the Constant block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what does your input variable look like? I use a structure:

```
variable1.time=[0 1 2];
variable1.signals.values=rand(1,3);
```

Comment: It is just a matrix C=[1 2;3 4]

Comment: simin is for time varying variables. You could specify the matrix just once at time=0, or just use a constant like Navan suggested